# Disable captive portal checking on Android 9

Tags: android, adb, captiveportal

How does one completely disable captive portal checking on Android 9 (on a Moto G7 Play in my case)?

Answers to similar questions, here and on other sites, suggest to change settings through the ADB shell.

What I have set so far with `adb shell`:
`settings put global captive_portal_mode 0`
`settings put global captive_portal_server 127.0.0.1`
`settings put global captive_portal_http_url localhost`
`settings put global captive_portal_https_url localhost`
`settings put global captive_portal_fallback_url localhost`
`settings put global captive_portal_detection_enabled 0`

Some of these settings should be redundant and I think the last one is for older Android versions, but I set all of them anyway to find one that would do the trick.

I restarted the phone and verified the settings with `adb settings get`. It still continues to contact connectivitycheck.gstatic.com, about 200 times a day.